# Where do you ask questions about home networking?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

It seems that Server Fault explicitly disallows questions about networking outside the workplace. Is there a reason for that? Where should those questions go - ie  Where do you ask questions about networking/setting up routers/APs/Firewalls/etc for one's home.

Answer (score 3):

Those questions seem to be acceptable on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

More specifically: If the question would be on-topic for Server Fault if asked about a company/enterprise network, it will almost certainly be on-topic for Super User if asked about a home network.

Purchase recommendation questions (e.g., "What router should I buy?"), however, will be off-topic in either place.